# Qt window bugs with OpenGL

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

[image: Snapshot of interface]

[image: Snapshot of interface after fullscreen]

I have created a Qt interface to visualise a 3D model (point  cloud) and an image. The issue is that when I switch to full screen, (using keystroke F1 for example), I do get my fullscreen mode as expected. But When I switch to normal mode, the 3D model disappears in the widget as shown in the bottom figure.

QGLWidget is inserted like this in QMainWindow:

QMainWindow : setCentralWidget(viewerWidget);

Our 3D Engine Class,OpenGLViewer inherits QGLWidget

the function for toggle full window goes like this:

```
void OpenGLViewer::toggleFullWindow()
{
    if (isFullScreen()) {
        setWindowFlags(Qt::Widget);
        showNormal();
    }
    else {
        setWindowFlags(Qt::Window);
        showFullScreen();
    }
}
```

My ui widget goes like this

```
QLabel* App::createViewerBox()
{
   viewerWidget = dynamic_cast<QWidget*>(viewer);
   QHBoxLayout *layoutHor = new  QHBoxLayout();
   QLabel *frame = new QLabel();
   layoutHor->addWidget(viewerWidget,Qt::AlignJustify);
   frame->setLayout(layoutHor);

   return frame;

}
```

Comment: What version of Qt are you using? What Qt wrappers for OpenGL are you using? Some of the deprecated wrappers have a refresh issue in Qt 5.

Comment: I am using QT 5.7.0 . I must admit since starting the project we are having so many issues with Qt.

Comment: QGLWidget is deprecated. (http://blog.qt.io/blog/2014/09/10/qt-weekly-19-qopenglwidget/) In the showEvent() of the parent for your OpenGL widget, try calling a function on your subclass that calls QGLWidget::updateGL().

Comment: By using class OpenGLViewer : public QOpenGLWidget instead of QGLWidget, the 3D model does not even show up this time.. I have a black window. Any idea? Thanks.